# Can 2 columns of nested divs be merged into a single column and then re-ordered using CSS?

Tags: css, mobile, layout, flexbox, responsive

So, I'm pretty certain it's not possible to do the following, but thought I'd ask anyway!

I've got 2 columns of content on my website design. Both have a wrapper div, floated, so they sit side by side. This looks fine on the desktop layout, and on the mobile (responsive) layout they currently both fill out to 100% width, and stack on top of each other.

What I'd really like to do is change the order of the nested divs inside each floated wrapper on the mobile layout so that, essentially, the two columns merge into one single column and the nested divs ordering changes as below:

```
DESKTOP
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8

MOBILE
1
5
2
3
6
7
8
4
```

Hope this is clear enough! I know I can use flexboxes to change the order on the mobile layout, but as far as I can get is to change the order only within each individual wrapper div. Have also tried floating the nested divs in various ways on the desktop layout, but to no avail.

EDIT:
Apologies, I should have pasted my code, either:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper-left">
    <div class="divInside div1">1</div>
    <div class="divInside div2">2</div>
    <div class="divInside div3">3</div>
    <div class="divInside div4">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper-right">
    <div class="divInside div5">5</div>
    <div class="divInside div6">6</div>
    <div class="divInside div7">7</div>
    <div class="divInside div8">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="divInside div1">1</div>
    <div class="divInside div2">2</div>
    <div class="divInside div3">3</div>
    <div class="divInside div4">4</div>
    <div class="divInside div5">5</div>
    <div class="divInside div6">6</div>
    <div class="divInside div7">7</div>
    <div class="divInside div8">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also here's an image to illustrate what I'm after. Sincere apologies, it's my first question here!

[image: Layout example]

Comment: for us to help you will need to include the current code you're using please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this may be possible but please provide the HTML structure..

Comment: If you know the height of the overall wrapper you can.

Comment: Make 4 parent div and then 2 child div in each..it will work.

Answer (score 1):

After the feedback on the comments, I change my answer using `flexbox` and `order` property as you point in your question that you have tried before. You do not need two wrappers to get it, instead.

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.divInside{
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  flex-basis: 49%;
}

.div1{
  order: 1;
}

.div2{
  order: 3;
}

.div3{
  order: 5;
}

.div4{
  order: 7;
}

.div5{
  order: 2;
}

.div6{
  order: 4;
}

.div7{
  order: 6;
}

.div8{
  order: 8;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
  .wrapper{
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .divInside{
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  
  .div3{
    order: 4;
  }
  
  .div4{
    order: 8;
  }
  
  .div8{
    order: 7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="divInside div1">1</div>
    <div class="divInside div2">2</div>
    <div class="divInside div3">3</div>
    <div class="divInside div4">4</div>
    <div class="divInside div5">5</div>
    <div class="divInside div6">6</div>
    <div class="divInside div7">7</div>
    <div class="divInside div8">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your demo div placement is wrong. 5 should be below 1 but not 2.check question back.

Comment: You've demonstrated what the OP (appears to) have already achieved. However, the core of the problem here is intermingling the elements from both columns with each other, and reordering them in some places.

Comment: @Leothelion Thanks for the feedback. I changed my answer :)

Comment: @Serlite Thank you for correct me. I have updated my answer :)

Comment: but still you did not get what op is needed.

Comment: @Leothelion Why not? It has the two columns on the first step and later the numbers ordered as his example.

Comment: If you change the height of the divs so they are all different the layout does not work, sorry. Thanks for trying though, valiant effort!

Answer (score 1):

It would be simple to solve this if you set the HTML to a css table structure (`display:table-row;` and `display:table-cell;`) setting the desired values for the Desktop format.

Then, using media queries you just set these display properties on the desktop size, and when it goes to mobile size it will stack one on top of the other:

```css
.main > div > div {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .main {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main > div {
    display: table-row;
  }
  
  .main > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>5</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>7</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for trying. Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work when the divs are all different heights. I've updated my original question with an image to illustrate what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Firefox ONLY Solution**

There is an experimental CSS `display` property of `contents` which will allow us to have our required structure but unbundle the respective wrappers as required.

I record it here for information purposes pending adoption by other browsers.

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JXQaKm)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.red > .divInside {
  background-color: red;
}
.yellow > .divInside {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.divInside {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  order: 0;
}
.red .divInside:nth-child(1) {} .red .divInside:nth-child(2) {
  order: 3;
}
.red .divInside:nth-child(3) {
  order: 5
}
.red .divInside:nth-child(4) {
  order: 8
}
.yellow .divInside:nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}
.yellow .divInside:nth-child(2) {
  order: 5
}
.yellow .divInside:nth-child(3) {
  order: 6
}
.yellow .divInside:nth-child(4) {
  order: 7
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: contents;
  }
  #container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper red">
    <div class="divInside">1</div>
    <div class="divInside">2</div>
    <div class="divInside">3</div>
    <div class="divInside">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper yellow">
    <div class="divInside">5</div>
    <div class="divInside">6</div>
    <div class="divInside">7</div>
    <div class="divInside">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There you go...fixed.